# function value constant function

Tags: functions

Let $f:(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with the property that $f(x)=f(x^4) ~ \forall x$ and $f(1/2)=a$. Show that the only function f satisfying this property is the constant function $f(x)=a$.
My work: I could only conclude that the function is symmetric about the y axis. How do I possibly proceed?

Comment: Hint: consider $f$ on sequences of the form $\left(x^{4^n}\right)_{n=0}^\infty$. Note that $x^{4^n} \to 0$ when $x \in (-1, 1)$, and use continuity.

Comment: this sequence dependent on both x and n

Comment: Well, for each $x \in (-1, 1)$, form a separate sequence in $n$. Regardless of the value of $x$ you started with, you should get convergence to $0$.

Comment: So, if the sequence, $t=(x4n)∞n=0$. $t$ is convergent to $0$. Since $f$ is a continuous function, $limf(t)=f(0)$ as $t$ goes to $0$

Comment: Yep! Notice that $f$ is constant on each of these sequences, and these sequences begin at some arbitrary $x \in (-1, 1)$. What does this tell you about $f$?

Comment: That f is a constant function for all x in the given domain

Comment: Exactly.${}{}{}$

Comment: Thankyou @user804886

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing up from the comments, we proceed to show $f$ is constant by showing $f(x) = f(0)$ for any $x \in (-1, 1)$. If $x \in (-1, 1)$, then
$$f(x) = f(x^4) = f(x^{16}) = \ldots = f\left(x^{4^n}\right) = \ldots$$
Since $|x| < 1$, we have $x^{4^n} \to 0$, so by continuity at $0$,
$$f(0) = f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} x^{4^n}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f\left(x^{4^n}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x) = f(x).$$
Hence, $f$ is constant; $f(x) = f(1/2) = a$ for all $x \in (-1, 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall x\in ]-1,1[:f(x)=f(x^{4^{n}})\\
\displaystyle\forall x\in ]-1,1[:\lim_{n \to \infty }x^{4^{n}}=0\\
 \Rightarrow \forall x\in ]-1,1[:f(x)=f(0)=cte $